# Are there any naming conventions for multiple inverse properties in EF Core or are attributes necessary?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

[This article](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) shows the following table example:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OnlineTeacher")]
    public int? OnlineTeacherId { get; set; }
    public Teacher OnlineTeacher { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClassRoomTeacher")]
    public int? ClassRoomTeacherId { get; set; }
    public Teacher ClassRoomTeacher { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("OnlineTeacher")]
    public ICollection<Course> OnlineCourses { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ClassRoomTeacher")]
    public ICollection<Course> ClassRoomCourses { get; set; }
}
```

I found that I could remove the `[ForeignKey(*)]` attributes and they still get created on the Courses table properly. However, if I remove BOTH `[InverseProperty]` attributes, EF throws an error when i build. Are there naming conventions for this just [like the foreign keys](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions#foreign-key)? My goal is to follow the naming conventions closely and reduce the amount of attribute/fluent based configuration.

Comment: You could do this better using `nameof` though, like `[InverseProperty(nameof(Course.ClassRoomTeacher))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I remove BOTH [InverseProperty] attributes, EF throws an error
>   when i build. Are there naming conventions for this just like the
>   foreign keys?

There is **no naming convention** defined by EF when many assocaitions of same type (e.g. 1-to-many) exit between two entities.

For example when you have one association between `EntityA` and `EntityB`. Let say it exists 1-to-* relation between `EntityA` and `EntityB`, it works well when you respect the convention. But when you put another 1-to-* relation between `EntityA` and `EntityB`, EF will need your help to know how associations are related. So you must use `InverseProperty` data annotation attribute or define the full relations through fluent configuration.

Comment: This is what I suspected unfortunately. I figured it would be easy on the inverse property (the `ICollection<EntityA>`) naming it <inverse property><your name of choice> like `EntityA_Items { get; set; }` should be easy enough for EF to figure out, especially since it works with foreign keys already.